Font rendering issue on Firefox compared to Chrome
I am using a Typekit font (Area Normal) and it shows differently on Chrome to Firefox on Mac.
The code is obviously identical, however, on Firefox there would appear to be a 0.58px gap appearing underneath the text meaning that the text is not central, despite a 17px padding on both top and bottom of the red element.
Changing the line height obviously just changes it on both and the gap below remains the same. How can I remove that gap below on Firefox?



Are you sure it comes from the font ? did you compare with like sans-serif or something more standard ?

Yes, if i change the font to Arial that gap below on Firefox disappears and the text centres

Are you able to provide a runnable snippet which shows the problem? I don’t understand why it is centered, ie doesn’t have space for descenders.
